Active state on menu element
I have a problem enabling the .active class for each menu item I click in the navbar of my website (which is built in HTML, CSS, JS).
I use a file nav.html to load the navbar in all my pages, with this code:


<header id="hero-header">
               <script>        AOS.init();
            </script>
    <div class="logo-container">
        <a href="home.html"><img class="logo-desktop" id="logo-hero" src="assets/img/logo.svg"></a>
        <a href="home.html"><img class="logo-mobile" id="logo-hero" src="assets/img/mobile-logo.svg"></a>
    </div>

    <ul>
        
        <li data-aos="fade-down" data-aos-duration="600"><a href="home.html" class="menu-item-desktop">Home</a></li>
        <!-- <li data-aos="fade-down" data-aos-duration="600"><a href="map.html" class="">Map</a></li> -->
        <div data-aos="fade-down" data-aos-duration="800" class="menu-item-desktop dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn">LifePulse ID</button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="before-donation.html">Before Donation</a>
                <a href="after-donation.html">After Donation</a>
                <a href="how-else-can-I-help.html" class="">How else can I help</a>
            </div>
        </div>                    
        <li data-aos="fade-down" data-aos-duration="1000"><a href="team.html" class="menu-item-desktop">Team</a></li> 
        <li data-aos="fade-down" data-aos-duration="1000"><a href="news.html" class="menu-item-desktop ">News</a></li>
        <li data-aos="fade-down" data-aos-duration="1200"><a href="partners.html" class="menu-item-desktop ">Partners</a></li> 
        <li data-aos="fade-down" data-aos-duration="1400"><a href="contact.html" class="menu-item-desktop ">Contact</a></li>
        
        <div data-aos="fade-down" data-aos-duration="1600" class="search-button">
            <form action="/search">
                <input type="search" name="q" id="search" placeholder="Type and click enter">
                <a href="#" id="btn-close">
                    <span class="fontawesome-close">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-times" style="color: #ffffff;"></i>
                    </span>
                </a>
                <a href="#" id="btn-search">
                    <span class="fontawesome-search">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass" style="color: #ffffff;"></i>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </form>
        </div>
    </ul>
    <div class="button-container">
        <a href="contact.html">
            <div class="magnetic">
                <div class="wrap">
                    <div class="span span-1 go"></div>
                    <div class="span span-2 go"></div>
                    <div class="span span-3 go"></div>
                    <div class="span span-4 go"></div>
                    <div class="span span-1 go"></div>
                    <img src="assets/img/hand.png">
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</header> 

<div id="hero-bottom">
    <div class="city">Thessaloniki, GR</div>
    <ul>
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/lifepulse_gr" target="_blank"><li><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram " style="color: #ffffff;"></i></li></a>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/lifepulsegreece"  target="_blank"><li><i class=" fa-brands fa-facebook-f social-icons fa-s" style="color: #ffffff;"></i></li></a>
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/lifepulse-blood-donation"  target="_blank"><li><i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin-in" style="color: #ffffff;"></i></li></a>       
    </ul>
</div>



I want each time I click on a menu item, this specific item to jump on active state. I tried creating a file menus.js with this code:


const links =document.querySelectorAll(".menu-item-desktop ");
links.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
     e.preventDefault();
     btn.classList.add("active")
  }));



and adding it at the bottom of the body tag in every html page, but it didn't work. What am I missing?

Please define "it didn't work". What goes wrong with your current code?

I use a file nav.html to load the navbar in all my pages - how exactly do you "load nav.html into all your pages"?   Sounds like you want to run your code after that happens.

What does console.log(document.querySelectorAll(".menu-item-desktop").length) give you?

@fdomn-m it returns 6. Also, about your other question, inside the body tag in every html page I have, I use:

with a corresponding div tag as a placeholder, and the menu loads.

6 is good, if it was 0 then the code would be running too soon.   Did you add that just before your const links= (ie do console.log(links.length))? or did you run it in the console after the page had loaded?

@fdomn-m I ran it in the console after the page has loaded.
Now I added it before my 'const links=' and I got 0 though. Still getting 6 if I ran it in the console.

You probably have to wait until the document is parsed and the DOM is complete. See MDN docs - DOMContentLoaded. You could also move the JavaScript in your nav.html (the AOS.init() call) to the bottom of the file. Would that help?

Yes, you get 6 because that's after your "header-load" script has run.  You get 0 at first because the code is running before the header has loaded - hence the request to clarify.  When your code is running, the header/footer have not loaded.  You need to move your event handler code to the complete callback of the .load

@PeterPointer FYI OP is loading the nav using $(function(){ $("#nav-placeholder").load("nav.html"); });  (see comments)

@PanosFusu Did you try my version?

@Godot I did but unfortunately the menu items don't change to active state.

@PanosFusu Apologies, I was delegating from the wrong container. I have updated. I cannot test my code since neither AJAX, nor localStorage is supported in SO snippets. If you really need, I can mock something in jsfiddle.net

@Godot only if you have some time, since this is about a minor update in my website. I surely do something wrong myself and it's still not working. I'm using the code you provided both inside a script tag at the end of the body tag AND in a different file (menus.js) which I import in my html page. None of these worked, but again I'm sure I do something wrong.

Have a look at my answer and the fiddle

Thank you both for your time! I was able to find a solution after some studying and chat gpt prompting. Thank you <3

If any answers helped you, please don't forget to give them an upvote.

What actually worked at the end, was having this script:


$(document).ready(function() {
                $("#nav-placeholder").load("nav.html", function() {
                    // Get current page URL
                    var url = window.location.pathname;
                    // Find the menu item that matches the current URL
                    $('#nav-placeholder a').each(function() {
                        if ($(this).attr('href') === url) {
                            $(this).addClass('active');
                        }
                    });
                });
            });



in all my html pages, just below the


<div id="nav-placeholder"></div>




Your issue is that the event handler code is running before the elements have loaded and thus does not add any events.
You have a number of options:

add the code to .load complete callback
use event delegation (see this answer (or the simpler jquery answer on that question as using jquery)

Putting your event handler code inside document load / doc.ready would not work as that would fire before your secondary load.
As provided in the comments, your code is currently (I'm assuming the event code is in the doc.ready, makes no difference)
$(function(){ 
    $("#nav-placeholder").load("nav.html"); 

    const links = document.querySelectorAll(".menu-item-desktop");
    links.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
       e.preventDefault();
       btn.classList.add("active")
    }));
});

Change this to add the event code inside the load callback:
$("#nav-placeholder").load("nav.html", function() {

    const links = document.querySelectorAll(".menu-item-desktop");
    links.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
       e.preventDefault();
       btn.classList.add("active")
    }));
});



Event delegation would be, using jquery as you've used jquery for doc/ready and load:
$(function(){ 
    $("#nav-placeholder").load("nav.html"); 

    $(document).on("click", ".menu-item-desktop", function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $(".active").removeClass("active");
       $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});


Can't thank you enough for your help and time! The event delegation approach worked at some extend: now all my items change into active state when clicked (and when I click a different menu item, the previous active item returns to default state). The problem with this code is that the links don't work.
So, I click an element, the state changes (THANK YOU FOR THAT <3) but I'm not redirected to the corresponding page.

"but I'm not redirected to the corresponding page" - that's because you have added e.preventDefault which ... prevents the default (navigation).   Remove that line and your code will then navigate.  At that point the new page will not have the highlight because it's a new page - at which point, do refer to @Godot 's answer to restore the navigation highlight when the page loads.  But that's not what was asked, it's what will happen when you fix what was asked.  Note @Godot's answer will need to be applied in combination with this answer (in the .load callback).

Guys I really appreciate the time you spent for my problem, I'm really amazed about how fast you reply as well. We (in fact you) figured out the origin of my issue (the active state change and the load) and I've already learned something new. So thank you from the bottom of my heart.

@fdomn-m - I realised later (due to comments posted by panos) that the nav is loaded into nav-placeholder - so my script will work if delegating from that container, without having to be run in the load callback

If you want to click on links that replaces the page you are on with another page AND have the nav items to be active? Then you need to store what has been clicked in localStorage.
Alternatively load the HTML pages from the links using the same .load method you use for the nav.html
If not, then use delegation because that is a simpler way
You need to delegate from the nearest STATIC container- the one you load the nav into
Also since you load the nav menu using .load, you need the script that handles the clicks to NOT be in that file since JS will not run in an  HTML page loaded using AJAX (which .load is).
This code needs to live in the page you load (external script is fine) and not in nav.html
Here is a jQuery version which will load the nav AND delegate
https://jsfiddle.net/x6ourewL/1/
$(() => { // page loading
  const activeURL = localStorage.getItem('activeURL');
  const $container = $('#nav-placeholder')
  .load('nav.html', function() {
    // AOS.init(); // if that is needed in the nav
    $links = $('.menu-item-desktop a');
    console.log(activeURL, $(`[href="${activeURL}"]`).attr('href'))
    $link = activeURL ? $(`[href="${activeURL}"]`).eq(0) : $links.eq(0);
    $link.addClass('active'); // activate the first or first of found link (if that makes sense)
  }) 
  .on('click', '.menu-item-desktop a', function() { // delegation
    localStorage.setItem('activeURL',$(this).attr('href')); // before the link loads the new page
  });
});

